# Conditions Ignored - IF statement inside Foreach loop

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, strpos

so I am running through an array containing different types of fruit, by using foreach.
Every time a fruit of that array matches a fruit within the string of $this-field (for example apples), the fruit shall get echoed.

Problem
What happens instead is that this code will simply list EVERY fruit within $fruits.
It does so even if I erase the whole strpos part and replace it by whatever I want like $test or something. It is like the conditioning within the if-loop is just getting totally ignored for some reason and I can't wrap my head around it. Please take a look at my code below.

```
foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
    if (strpos($this->field('has_apples'), $fruit) !== false ) {
        echo $fruit;
    };
}
```

EDIT

```
$fruits = array("banana","apple","cherry");
```

The other one returns a string stemming from a blob like "kiwi,apple,coconut,orange". Does that help?

```
$this->field('has_apples')
```

...is returning a string from the table "has_apples", that will look like this: "banana,apple,cherry,coconut,walnut,watermelon".

For what ever reason if I just use this code, without running through the foreach-loop it works perfectly:

```
if (strpos($this->field('has_apple'), 'apple') !== false ) {
                    echo 'Yes, there is an apple inside the string';
};
```

Comment: Show us the definition of `$fruits` and `$this->field('has_apples')`? What are the exact values?

Comment: Oh yes of course

'$fruits = array("banana","apple","cherry");'

The other one returns a string stemming from a blob like "kiwi,apple,coconut,orange".

Does that help?

Comment: Yes it does, but you should have updated your question instead. [For me it works](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4b66229204c6fc7b37252644180d692835dde11f) with the provided data. Assuming `$this->field('has_apples') === 'kiwi,apple,coconut,orange'` and `'$fruits === array("banana","apple","cherry")` is true and it still shows you all elements in $fruits, then there's something wrong with your Server. If thats not the case then provide [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I am Sorry, I just edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Problem solved. $this->field('has_apples') did in fact return an object, not a string. Thank you very much.